# Find spectral theorem of $A$ and find its singular eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, svd

The rotation matrix 
$$A=\pmatrix{ \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -\sin \theta & \cos \theta}$$
has complex eigenvalues $\{e^{\pm i\theta}\}$ corresponding to eigenvectors $\pmatrix{1 \\i}$ and $\pmatrix{1 \\ -i}$.

Now I want to find $A = \lambda_1v_1v_1^T + \lambda_2v_2v_2^T$. and then I want to find singular values of $A$ (which I believe only exist in SVD)

**Step 1:** make $v_1,v_2$ orthonormal vectors.

**Step 2:** Calculate $A$, by the spectrom theorem I wrote above.

**Step 3:** Calculate $A^TA$ because we want to find singular values of $A$.

**Step 4:** How do I find singular values now of $A$? do I need to use the eigenvectors I found above? $A^TAv = \lambda_{1,2}v$?

**Any help is highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the singular values of a matrix $A$ are defined as the (positive) square roots of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$.

Comment: How can I find $A$? , do I need to find $A^2$ for singular values of $A$?

Comment: I thought $A$ is given? Well in your case $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, so $A^*A = I$ the identity matrix. The eigenvalues of $I$ are obviously $1$, and $\sqrt{1} = 1$, so your singular values would be both $1$, if I'm not mistaken...